# Button Click gets queued and doesn't get fired unless scrolled

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

Hi I am trying to use [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) with my ListView. I am adding an ArrayAdapter as first subadapter and a button to as the second one. Now the OnItemClick on ArrayAdapter works great, but I am not able to click on the button. If I click it 4-5 times, the clicks gets queued and gets fired when I scroll the listview.

This is what my code looks like -

```
    adapter = new TransactionAdapter(this, R.layout.transaction_list_item,
            transactionData);

    mergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();

    loadMoreButton = new Button(this);
    loadMoreButton.setText(getString(R.string.button_load_more));
    loadMoreButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    loadMoreButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    loadMoreButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    loadMoreButton.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    loadMoreButton.setFocusable(false);
    loadMoreButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    loadMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppManager.getInstance().getStartCal().add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            loadTransactions();
        }
    });

    mergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapter);
    mergeAdapter.addView(loadMoreButton);
    listView.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
```

Any way I can fire the clicks at real time, without waiting for the ListView to scroll.

Comment: I suggest you create a temporary `Adapter` class that returns your `Button` as the one-and-only `View`, and try using it in a `ListView` without `MergeAdapter`. I expect you will have the same problem, and therefore the problem is not with `MergeAdapter`.

Comment: Yeah I found out the same. I'll check with the temp adapter class too. Thanks a lot for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by `CommonsWare`, I created a second adapter which returns just the button. THis solves the problem. So I guess you shouldn't use `MergeAdapter#addView()` method for any interactive views. Instead just use another adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and found a solution how this also works with `MergeAdapter#addView()`. You have to explicitly enable the view when adding it: `mMergeAdapter.addView(view, true);`. This finally solved the problem for me.